# Node JS -URL Parameters simplified like example.com/profile/me

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-rewriting

How do i shorten the url which is something like this 'www.example.com/movies?year=2009&genre=action' to 'www.example.com/movies/2009/action' ?

Im using node js, i have developed apis which, with a get request returns JSON array. But i need to render the page. If i use res.render(page) in my API, then i can send json to my mobile application. So how do i achieve this? 
Say, facebook.com/mark- retrieves profile of Mark
 facebook.com/john - retrieves profile of John

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to use [express](http://expressjs.com/).  From the [Scotch.io tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters#specific-routing-for-specific-parameters) and [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render):

```
app.get('/movies/:year/:genre', function(req, res) {
    // How you retrieve moviesJSON depends on your database
    var moviesJSON = findMoviesByGenre(req.params.genre); 
    res.render('MyView', moviesJSON);
});
```

Comment: that will return values to the client.. but i want to render a page..say if the move is of genre action /action or if the genre is thriller /thriller it should render page with all movies

Comment: If you're using different views (thriller.html, action.html), use different routes.  Otherwise you have to return values to the client.  You can always look up the movies from your database in the router code.  I edited my answer to show this case.

Comment: So in case i need to return json values to the client..do i need to write separate APIS?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  You can pass JSON objects or strings with `res.render()`.  [Looks like you have to](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render), actually.